# code coverage in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

How to cover `if (serviceCatalogueRecord.RecordType.Name != 'Service 3')` in the test class? I have used `serviceCatalogueRecord.RecordType.Name != 'Service Level 3';` in my test class which is in the get property, but it throwing the following error:

> expressions cannot be statement

**apex class:**

```
public class ServiceCatalogueWrap {           
    public Service_Catalogue__c serviceCatalogueRecord { get; set; }

    public List<Service_Catalogue__c> childServices {
        get {
            if (serviceCatalogueRecord.RecordType.Name != 'Service Level 3') childServices = [SELECT Id, Parent_Contracted__c, Name, Description__c,RecordType.Name FROM Service_Catalogue__c WHERE Parent__c =: serviceCatalogueRecord.Id OR Level__c =: serviceCatalogueRecord.Id];

            return childServices;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
ServiceCatalogueTreeViewCtrl.ServiceCatalogueWrap scWrap = new ServiceCatalogueTreeViewCtrl.ServiceCatalogueWrap(serCat2);  
serviceCatalogueRecord.RecordType.Name != 'Service 3';
```

Comment: Hi sfdclearner, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. This is not a question, since you haven't asked anything. If you would like to learn the basics of unit testing, the **[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)** platform may be a good place to start.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sure will check it.I have modified the question where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually instantiate the record with a `RecordType` of some other name, then call the getter. For example:

```
Service_Catalogue__c record = new Service_Catalogue__c();
record.RecordType = [
    SELECT Name FROM RecordType
    WHERE Name != 'Blacklisted Value'
    LIMIT 1
];
// create child data to be queried

Test.startTest();
    MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(record);
    List<Service_Catalogue__c> children = wrapper.childServices;
Test.stopTest();

// assert proper children were queried
```

Comment: // create child data to be queried - means we need to insert the the data for Service_Catalogue__c

Comment: @sfdclearner Yes, the query you are trying to get coverage for. You will get code coverage for that line either way, but will not be able to verify behavior without creating the data.

Comment: It covered ,For else part do we need to write in a separate method? and how to get '(List<Service_Catalogue__c>) con.getRecords()' in test  class .I have  List<Service_Catalogue__c> but the above part didnt get covered in the class

Comment: @sfdclearner Yes, *unit* tests should each cover one unit, try to make them atomic. So you would create separate test where you use `= '<blacklisted_value>'` instead of `!= '<blacklisted_value>'`.